# Create a DSN for pyodbc similar to PHP PDO. Is it possible?

Tags: python, mysql, odbc, pyodbc

I use **PHP PDO** to connect a **MySql** Db and it works great. I have something like:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name';
$user_db = 'admin';
$password = 'password';

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user_db, $password);
```

Now I need to load same database from a **python** script and I have to use **pypodbc module**

But I'm getting some issue:

If I do (on Python):

```
pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MySQL};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=database_name;UID=admin;PWD=password;')
```

I got en error on log:

> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open
>   lib '/usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so' : file not found (0)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)")

If i check the /etc/odbcinst.ini i can see:

```
# Driver from the mysql-connector-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC package
[MySQL]
Description     = ODBC for MySQL
Driver          = /usr/lib/libmyodbc5.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64        = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage       = 1
```

I tried to add the the package **mysql-connector-odbc** by YUM  and i got **mysql-connector-odbc.x86_64 0:5.1.5r1144-7.el6**

And then running my script I got a new error:

> /usr/local/bin/python2.7: relocation error: /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so: symbol strmov, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient_r.so.16 with link time reference

It seems this version is not compatible with MySql which I have: **5.5.37-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)**

I did a YUM REMOVE to restore previous conf.

And now ? Any suggestions ?  **Thanks!**

**My configuration:**

My Server: CENTOS 6.6 x86_64 virtuozzo
MySql: 5.5.37-cll - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I fixed it!

```
yum install unixODBC-devel 
yum install mysql-connector-odbc 
yum install openssl098e
```

and than:

```
rpm -ivh libmysqlclient16-5.1.69-1.w5.x86_64.rpm
```

Now the

```
pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={MySQL};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=database_name;UID=admin;PWD=password;')
```

works!! yeah!